# PHP Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce

```
echo '<td' . $times_class . '>' .
     date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time ) .
     '<br />' . $time . '<br />' .
     human_time_diff( $time ) .
     $this->display_past_time( $time ) . '</td>';
```

That's the code that is giving me the error. I tried searching and it said something about `DateTime` or so. But I have 0 php skills, i just saw my error file and located the string.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($time);` ?

Comment: As @Rizier123 said do a var_dump($time) BEFORE the echo command  in your code. We need to know what data type it is.

Comment: Sorry no idea what you just asked. I don't know any PHP or something like that. I am having trouble with my website and my provider isn't really helping. checked my error.log and it said that on line 193 (the above code) was giving this error. Its for a plugin called Debug bar cron for wordpress. Here is the pastebin for that entire file: http://pastebin.com/TdLG781U  (Line 193)

Comment: Without access to the source code (which you do not seem to have) I don't think anyone can help. Error.log files are great to tell you where the exception occurred, but we need to know the value of $time in the code. If that is not in your error log dump...well...Sorry.

Comment: I do have access to all the files. What should I do? As in: What should I put in that file to give you the var dump?

Comment: Above the echo line in your example code put in this code: var_dump($time);

Comment: Then run the program or access the web page that is showing this error. Post the response here. If var_dump does not appear in your error log or on the web page then use this command: echo var_export($time, true);

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gy4PATEP There you can see with and without. :) Thanks really appreciated you are taking time to look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what can be done. Look for where I put // ******** INSERT THIS CODE *********

```
private function display_events( $events ) {
                if ( is_null( $events ) || empty( $events ) )
                        return;

                echo '<table class="zt-debug-bar-cron-event-table" cellspacing="0">';
                echo '<thead><tr>';
                echo '<th class="col1">' . __( 'Next Execution', 'zt-debug-bar-cron' ) . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="col2">' . __( 'Hook', 'zt-debug-bar-cron' ) . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="col3">' . __( 'Interval Hook', 'zt-debug-bar-cron' ) . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="col4">' . __( 'Interval Value', 'zt-debug-bar-cron' ) . '</th>';
                echo '<th class="col5">' . __( 'Args', 'zt-debug-bar-cron' ) . '</th>';
                echo '</tr></thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';

                foreach ( $events as $time => $time_cron_array ) {
                        foreach ( $time_cron_array as $hook => $data ) {
// ******** INSERT THIS CODE *********
echo var_export($time, true);
                                // Add a class if past current time
                                $times_class = time() > $time && 'No' == $this->_doing_cron ? ' class="past"' : '';

                                echo '<tr>';

echo '<td' . $times_class . '>' .     date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $time ) . '<br />' . $time . '<br />' . human_time_diff( $time ) . $this->display_past_time( $time ) . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . wp_strip_all_tags( $hook ) . '</td>';
```

...

Comment: When run this should output some information about the $time variable.

Comment: Now it's giving me under the different titels this in one ong row


http://pastebin.com/mYaJEywr

Comment: Hmmmm... I'm not sure what a line of random digits means and is not helpful. Dang. Remove the code I told you to insert and see if the original error comes back.

Comment: If you get the original error then try inserting this line: echo print_r($time, true);

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think this is an error in the Debug Bar Cron plug in itself. Can you uninstall the plugin and reinstall it?  Or leave it uninstalled if the plug in is not critical to your WP page? Here is their web page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/

Comment: Thanks, i wrote to them and deactivated it for now. Yes it's not breaking my page but its spamming my error.log file and as I am trying to fix different problems it's cluttering all over the place. I really appreciate you thanking your time. Thanks again and have a good day.